# End of script output before headers: index.php - composer, noherczeg_breadcrumb, laravel

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, laravel-3

I can't get to work composer package https://github.com/noherczeg/breadcrumb on shared 111webhost hosting, my app is written in laravel 3.

I installed composer using this bundle:
https://github.com/benedmunds/Laravel-Composer

I get this error:
End of script output before headers: index.php

When I even try to execute the package by creating variable:
$this->breadcrumb = new \Noherczeg\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb(URL::base());

Wonder if anyone had problems with running composer packages on 111webhost.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Rather than sorting this issue I created my own dynamic breadcrumbs solution without using composer.